# css3 keyframes with weebly

Tags: css, weebly

I have the following code:

```
div.slide-right {
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

div.slide-right {
animation: 2s slide-right;
}

@keyframes slide-right {
  from {
    margin-left: -100%;
    width: 100%; 
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
```

Right now the animations are starting 2s after the page loads, and I want to start them either when the element is visible by the user or when the mouse is over some element. Preferably the first one.

The things is I'm using Weebly and it is a little difficult to add jquery and this stuff. Is there any easier way of doing this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/, it is as easy as importing the dependencies in the code snippets in Weebly and then add the class like it is explained in the web page.

```
<div class='animatedParent'>
    <h2 class='animated bounceInDown'>It Works!</h2>
</div>
```